Minimum elastic instance count Azure App Service
Currently, I am running a Dockerized Java Spring Boot application using Azure App Service. The App Service plan configuration is B1. When I display the App Service in JSON View, I notice a parameter called minimumElasticInstanceCount with a value of 0 in siteConfig. I would like to understand what this parameter means. Could someone please explain it to me?

Thank you for all your help.

it only applies when you have an elastic plan => function premium i think

If that’s the case, this parameter only affects Azure Functions and doesn’t impact Azure App Service (Web App). Did I understand correctly?

Yes you can ignore this setting for your use case

documentation (here) is saying: Number of minimum instance count for a site. This setting only applies to the Elastic Plans

minimumElasticInstanceCount is a parameter used in Autoscaling. It is used to define the number of instances that should be available at the minimum when the load is very low. You can see more about autoscaling at Microsoft TechCommunity - Apps on Azure Blog

Thank you for explained. However, for all other Web apps where the parameter minimumElasticInstanceCount is set to 1, they continue to operate normally. Only this Web app, with minimumElasticInstanceCount set to 0, experiences random restarts. Could this be related?

yes when there are no requests the app may be stopped and then started when the requests come in. This may look like a restart for you and response time may be slower for the requests that come after the cold start.

The minimumElasticInstanceCount parameter in Azure App Service's siteConfig controls the minimum number of instances that are always running for apps deployed on an Elastic Premium (EP) App Service Plan. It helps ensure that a baseline number of instances are ready, reducing cold starts and improving responsiveness.
Since you’re using the B1 (Basic) App Service Plan, this setting is not relevant, as it only applies to Elastic Premium Plans.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-automatic-scaling?tabs=azure-portal
